# Not able to extract number from a Image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am developing an application to read the numbers from an image using opencv in Python 3. I first converted the image to gray scale,then Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise, then Apply threshold to get image with only black and white, then Write the image to local disk to do some ..., then apply tesseract to recognise the number for python.

I need to extract the numbers from the image. I am new to openCV. Does anybody know any other method to get the result??

I have share the image link bellow, i was trying to extract from that image.  Thanks in advance

https://drive.google.com/file/d/141y-3okLPGP_STje14ukSqSHcgtwMdRO/view?usp=sharing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

# Path of working folder on Disk
src_path = "/Users/sougata.a.roy/Desktop/Images/"

def get_string(img_path):
    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Write image after removed noise
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.jpg", img)

    #  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 31, 2)

    # Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + 'thres.jpg', img)

    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres.jpg"), lang='eng')



    return result


print('--- Start recognize text from image ---')
print(get_string(src_path + 'abcdefg195.jpg'))

print("------ Done -------")
```

365

Comment: Is `kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)` intended? I suppose, dilation and erosion using a scalar `1` as the kernel won't change the input at all.

Comment: Thank for the reply @HansHirse, actually I was trying to do clear any noise, although my pic is clear